# Cisco Anyconnect NAT access from LAN?

Tags: nat, anyconnect

On my professional laptop, with Cisco Anyconnect, LAN access is not allowed. So all routes are overwritten, even when entered manually.

I can get admin rights temporary to install some things, but I'm not supposed to change Cisco profile, etc. With Vbox, NAT access works perfectly! And installing the Vbox new adapter is not forbidden.

I don't know how to do the same from a physical PC, is there some way using again NAT access?

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. That said, don't try to circumvent security controls of your organization. At worst, you might get fired and sued for damages.

Comment: Using Vbox with a personal VM , seems to be a security issue, so.  But I understand your answer.